# How can i send with React component mail?

Tags: reactjs, email, ref, react-to-pdf

Sending the page as pdf seems like the most logical, I'm using react-to-pdf to convert it to pdf but I have no idea what to do to send mail directly without downloading it, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. I look for it on web . Creator of reaft-pdf say it clearly in [this github issue](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/963#issuecomment-812935185)  .

And [this link](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/963#issuecomment-694706617) for simple solve . Briefly download and send ...